# Liferay Get Structure name in schedule.jsp

Tags: liferay, hook

I am creating a new Web Content using Web Content Display. When I select a structure can I get the structure name in Scheduling tab(hook file: \html\portlet\journal\article\schedule.jsp).

Currently I am using jQuery and using $( ".structure-name-label" ).html() but this is not quite satisfying. See the attachment.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there with getting the name of the Structure! Try the following code:

```
String structureName = JournalStructureLocalServiceUtil.getStructure(groupId, structureId).getName(Locale.US, true);
```

The part that says getName(`Locale.US, true`); will get the name of the structure with the Locale for US, or if there isn't one for the Locale US it will return the default Locale version.

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: article.getStructureId()! but article is null for New Web Content.

Comment: And the first??